# Filtering multiple retweets from Tweepy stream - Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy 3.10 to make a retweet bot which runs from a stream at the moment. It can filter out my own retweets, however if anyone else retweets something I've retweeted it crashes. How would be best to filter out items which I've already retweeted?

I tried adding:

```
if tweettext.startswith("rt @") == True:
   return
```

But that didn't end up filtering the way I hoped it would.
The current logic is:

```
def on_status(self, tweet):
    # This tweet is a reply or I'm its author so, ignore it
    if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None or \
            tweet.user.id == self.me.id:
        return
    else:
        # Retweets based on the above logic
        tweet.retweet()

    print(f"{tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}")
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this question in the future, the solution was quite simple. Add in a "try" function to ignore if an error is generated when trying to retweet but cant:

```
def on_status(self, tweet):
    # This tweet is a reply or I'm its author so, ignore it
    if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None or \
            tweet.user.id == self.me.id:
        return
    try:
        # Retweets based on the above logic
        tweet.retweet()
    # checking if the tweet is a retweet (exception added)
    except Exception:
        return

    print(f"{tweet.user.name}:{tweet.text}")
```